# What happens when during color blending when colors go out of the range

Tags: opengl, blending

Say I have such blending equation and coefficients that colors go out of the range for example

```
Source color: (0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0)
Destination color: (0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0) 
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
```

Should colors be normalized after calculation or they are being clamped? What is defined by the GL standard, I can't find it.

Comment: I guess that nothing will happen during blending. The conversion to the data-format of the framebuffer would happen afterwards. And there the same thing will happen as if you write outputs from your fragment shader that are larger than the possible data (clamping). What exactly happens mainly depends on the format of the color buffer. For a RGB32F buffer, not much will happen.

Comment: @BDL, what does it mean "not much will happen"? In case if have `(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)` I have red. What color I have in case of  `(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)`?

Answer (score 1):

In general, color vectors are never "normalized" automatically in the GL. They are clamped at the various fragment processing stages if that operation makes sense for the current format of the color buffer, and they are never clamped when using a floating-point format.

[OpenGL 4.6 Core Profile specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

**Section 17.3.6 Blending:**

> If the color buffer is fixed-point, the components of the source and
>   destination values and blend factors are each clamped to [0, 1] or
>   [−1, 1] respectively for an unsigned normalized or signed normalized
>   color buffer prior to evaluating the blend equation. If the color
>   buffer is floating-point, no clamping occurs. **The resulting four
>   values are sent to the next operation.**

So if blending is enabled, the *input* values are clamped unless you use an unnormalized floating point color buffer. THe *result* of the blending is not clamped.

The next operation is 
**Section 17.3.7 sRGB Conversion**:

> [Note: `cl` is the input value of the operation (which is the resulting value of the blending stage), and `cs` is the resulting value of the sRGB conversion, with `cs = cl` if sRGB conversion is disabled]
>
> The resulting `cs`values for R, G, and B, and the unmodified A form a new RGBA color value. **If the color buffer is fixed-point, each component is clamped
>   to the range [0, 1] and then converted to a fixed-point value using equation 2.3.** The resulting four values are sent to the subsequent dithering operation.